# How i can get Latitude and Longitude in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

i am developing app in Blackberry which have GPS Functionality. so first i want to get Current latitude and longitude but it will dipslay like **time out while waiting for GPS loaction.** Below in my code for getting lat and long of current location.

```
public class LocationScreen extends MainScreen 
{
      public LocationScreen() 
      {
        super();
        final LabelField lfLocation = new LabelField();
        new Thread()
        {
          public void run() 
          {
            LocationHandler lh = new LocationHandler();
            final String msg = "Long: " + lh.getCurrentLongitude() + ", Lat: " + lh.getCurrentLatitude();

            Application.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
            {
              public void run() 
              {
                lfLocation.setText(msg);
                add(new LabelField("Lat and Long=="+msg));
              }
            });
          }
        }.start();
        this.add(lfLocation);
      }
    }

**Second Class**

public class LocationHandler 
{
  private LocationProvider locationProvider;
  private Location currentLocation;
  public LocationHandler()  
  {
    try 
    {
      locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
      currentLocation = locationProvider.getLocation(60);
    }
    catch (final Exception e) 
    {
      Application.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
      {
        public void run() 
        {
          Status.show(e.getMessage());
        }
      });
    }
  }
  public double getCurrentLongitude() 
  {
    if(currentLocation != null)
      return currentLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
    return -1;
  }
  public double getCurrentLatitude() 
  {
    if(currentLocation != null)
      return currentLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
    return -1;
  }
```

what i am doing mistake in my code please help me.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make simple `Thread` and write down below code in `run method` .

```
private BlackBerryCriteria blackBerryCriteria = null;
private BlackBerryLocation blackBerryLocation = null;
private BlackBerryLocationProvider blackBerryLocationProvider = null;
double lat = 0.0;
double lng = 0.0;

blackBerryCriteria = new BlackBerryCriteria();

    if(GPSInfo.isGPSModeAvailable(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_CELLSITE)) 
    {
        blackBerryCriteria.setMode(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_CELLSITE);
    }
    else if(GPSInfo.isGPSModeAvailable(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_ASSIST)) 
    {
        blackBerryCriteria.setMode(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_ASSIST);
    }
    else if(GPSInfo.isGPSModeAvailable(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_AUTONOMOUS)) 
    {
        blackBerryCriteria.setMode(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_AUTONOMOUS);
    }
    else 
    {
        blackBerryCriteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        blackBerryCriteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);
    }

try {
            blackBerryLocationProvider = (BlackBerryLocationProvider) BlackBerryLocationProvider.getInstance(blackBerryCriteria);
            blackBerryLocation = (BlackBerryLocation) blackBerryLocationProvider.getLocation(60);

            QualifiedCoordinates qualifiedCoordinates = blackBerryLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates();

            lat = qualifiedCoordinates.getLatitude();
            lng = qualifiedCoordinates.getLongitude();}catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in location :"+e.toString());
            System.out.println("Error in location :"+e.getMessage());
        }
```

Try this it working fine in my device using `BIS`. 
i hope it will help you ..

Answer (score 0):

Try This code.....

```
public class GetLatLon {
private LocationProvider provider,_locationProvider;
public static Timer timer;
double longitude=0.0,lattitude=0.0;
Criteria criteria;
public GetLatLon()
{   
    startLocationUpdate();
}

public  class LocationListenerImpl implements LocationListener {
    public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, final Location location) {
        System.out.println("---Location Updated-----");
        if (location.isValid()) {
            System.out.println("---Location Valid----");
                    longitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
                    lattitude= location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
                    System.out.println("Lattitude :-=============================="+lattitude);
                    System.out.println("Longitude :-=============================="+longitude);
                    _locationProvider.setLocationListener(null, 0, 0, 0);
            }else{
            System.out.println("else NOT valid--Cellsite valide=-----");
            setupCriteria();
            setupProvider();
        }
        System.out.println("---Location Not Valid----");
    }
    public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState) {}
}

private void setupCriteria() {
    criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);
}


private void setupProvider() {
    try {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
           System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);
        provider.setLocationListener(
                new LocationListenerImpl(), 1, 1, 1);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.toString());
    }
}
public void startLocationUpdate() 
{
    try{
        _locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
        if (_locationProvider != null) {
            _locationProvider.setLocationListener(
                    new LocationListenerImpl(), 1, 1, 1);
        } 
    }catch(LocationException le){
        System.out.println("----Exception Of Location--"+le);
    }
}
}
```